# Files are deployed to heroku, but there is no files showing with bash command

Tags: git, heroku, deployment

Deployed correctly with the command:

`git push heroku master`

But file can't be found when executing:

`heroku run python manage.py deploy`

Checking if files are existed:

```
heroku run bash
ls -al
```

It shows no file on heroku.
Did I miss anything?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved after deleting and re-creating the heroku app.